# How do I plot these values against each other?

Tags: arrays, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a .csv file which has 3 value-types: Time, Torque and Angle.
The values are saved in seperate columns like that:

Row 1: Time1, Torque1, Angle1, ..., TimeX,TorqueX,AngleX.

The rest of the rows are the Values (745 Values each Instance and Variable)

So first I transposed the DataFrame and seperated it into the different variables.

```
time=df_trans.iloc[::3, :]
torque=df_trans.iloc[1: : 3, :]
angle=df_trans.iloc[2 : :3,:]
```

So now I have DataFrames with the Times, Torques and Angles of the X instances. (In this example 5 instances) Each Instance having a row and the columns being the values of the Instance.

For example print(angle):

```
                           0    ...               745
01.01.1990 01:33:51 Angle   0  ...  5225,68408203125
01.01.1990 01:35:09 Angle   0  ...    5186,560546875
01.01.1990 01:35:58 Angle   0  ...  3794,25634765625
01.01.1990 01:37:11 Angle   0  ...  3230,36791992188
01.01.1990 01:37:57 Angle   0  ...  3794,13012695313


[5 rows x 746 columns]
```

Now I want to plot the angles against the torque of the Instance for all instances in one plot, but I can't seem to get it working.

The code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Kurven.csv", sep=';', header=[0])
df_trans=df.transpose()

time=df_trans.iloc[::3, :]
time

torque=df_trans.iloc[1: : 3, :]
torque

angle=df_trans.iloc[2::3,:]
angle
```

Then I tried plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot(angle,torque)
```

got this Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Then I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

for i, j in angle,torque:
  plt.plot(i,j)
```

Got this Error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Try `for i, j in zip(angle,torque):` and then `plt.scatter(i,j)`

Comment: tried it, sadly it didn't work out, got a straight line and the indixes as x and y axis